# How to make data in NavigationLink scrollable swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

Im a beginner in swift, trying to create an app with two screens. Screen A with a list of data. When user selects an item from list the item details will show in Screen B. Thats All.

I used below code. everything is working fine. when i select item in list, screen B displays with data.
But the issue is data in screen B is not scrollable.

Here im using a NavigationLink to display data. Tried adding a ScrollView but does not work.

Please let me know what change required to make content in NavigationLink scrollable.

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {

    NavigationView() {
        VStack{
            List(modelDisease) { myList in

                ScrollView(.vertical,showsIndicators: true){
                    VStack{
                NavigationLink(
            destination: Text( myList.data) .padding()) {
        HStack {
            Text("\(myList.idValue)").frame(width: 50, height: 10, alignment: .leading)
            VStack {
                Text(myList.name)
            }
        }.font(.title)
                }
                }
                }
    }
    }.navigationBarTitle("Ayurvedic Remedies")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Destination is simply a Text() view.

Comment: Other than text view Could you please suggest which one will provide scroll feature?@TusharSharma

Comment: create your own custom view, and assign that as destination view.

Comment: thanks, Could you please provide a tutorial or sample code to refer.@TusharSharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you probably want your destination to be its own view. Right now, you have a `List` and a `ScrollView`, which is redundant, so you probably want that `ScrollView` as part of the destination. It might look something like this (based on your original code, which is missing the `modelDisease` type and declaration):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    //modelDisease must be declared here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(modelDisease) { myList in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: DestinationView(data: myList.data)) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("\(myList.idValue)").frame(width: 50, height: 10, alignment: .leading)
                        VStack {
                            Text(myList.name)
                        }
                    }.font(.title)
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("Ayurvedic Remedies")
    }
}


struct DestinationView : View {
    var data : String
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text(data)
        }.padding()
    }
}
```